# Vim - delete until previous word (excluding the previous word)

Tags: vim, cpu-word

Is there a way to delete until the previous word in vim (without deleting parts of the previous word itself)?

For example, so that the result is as follows (the pipe character '|' is the cursor position):

```
before: one   two   three   |four
after:  one   two   three|four
```

Another example:

```
before: one   two   three   fo|ur
after:  one   two   three|ur
```

Is there a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to use `ge`, however it is inclusive and not quite right for this application. Instead use a search, `?`, with the delete command.

```
d?\><cr>
```

This deletes (`d`) backwards (exclusively) by searching (`?`) until it finds an end of word boundary (`\>`).

For more help see:

```
:h ?
:h exclusive
:h /\>
```

Comment: This was not exactly what I was looking for, but it gave me the idea to search for the pattern via '?', which is worth the tick. Down below I posted the mappings that I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Using 'T' option

```
dTe ........... delete until (before) 'e'
```

Answer (score 2):

Combination of

- <kbd>db</kbd> (delete to beginning of current word) and
- <kbd>diw</kbd> (delete inner word, (also all spaces between words))

Answer (score 0):

Peter Rincker gave me the following idea:

```
"My custom text objects (move until one character before word)
nnoremap <silent> [ ?\S\zs\s<cr>
nnoremap <silent> ] /\s\S<cr>
vnoremap <silent> [ ?\S\zs\s<cr>
vnoremap <silent> ] /\s\S<cr>
nnoremap <silent> d[ d?\S\zs\s<cr>
nnoremap <silent> d] d/\s\S<cr>
nnoremap <silent> c[ c?\S\zs\s<cr>
nnoremap <silent> c] c/\s\S<cr>
```

Meanings:
`?` - search backwards
`/` - search forwards
`\S` - search for non white space character
`\s` - search for white space character
`<cr>` - press enter (finishes the command)
`\zs` - places cursor to this position. Lookup ´help \zs´, for more accurate info.

Example:

```
nnoremap <silent> [ ?\S\zs\s<cr>
```

When pressing the `[` button, search backwards  (`?`), for a non white space character (`\S`) followed by a white space character (`\s`). Put the cursor in between the white space and non white space character (`\zs`). Enter the command (`<cr>`).

Comment: You can create an operator pending mapping via `onoremap` to avoid making `c` & `d` mappings. You can also avoid side-effects of mutating the search register, `"/`, by using the `search()` function. e.g. `onoremap <silent> [w :<c-u>call search('\>', 'b')<cr>` & `onoremap <silent> ]w :<c-u>call search('\s\S')<cr>`. See `:h :omap` & `:h search()`